# What is parameter chaining in CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have read an article about the benefits of CNN. One of the points was "**parameter chaining"**. What does it mean? And how does it make **CNN** more convenient?

Comment: I agree with above comment, please give us the reference using this phrase. Otherwise this may be unanswerable, since different authors may use same phrases while meaning different things.